# Как отключить предосмотр ссылок discord.py Send?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Как отключить предпросмотр ссылок когда отправляешь сообщения через discord py

Comment: Попробуйте отправлять ссылки в значках больше/меньше. Например: `<https://www.google.ru/>`

Comment: @ГеннадийП это не со всем так работает как мне ннужно. Возможно ли вовсе это отключить?

Comment: Это работает именно так как вам нужно. Предпросмотр отключается в клиенте и бот на это не может повлиять.